# I can't find my nut

Tags: robinson-crusoe

In chapter four of The Adventures of Robinson Crusoe, at the very first section, how do you get the last nut?  I found the first two that were hidden objects, but the third one involves a puzzle and I can't work out what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the nuts is hidden behind the skeleton. In order to get to it you have to click on the hanging skeleton until you get it to swing.